# Double deletion error with shared_ptr C++

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr

I have the following class design:

```
struct compare{
template <typename T>
bool operator()(const T& a, const T&b){ return *a < *b;}
};

class Trans;

typedef set<shared_ptr<Trans>, compare > TransPointerSet;

class Place{

  // other data members
 TransPointerSet nextTrans;

public:

  // constructor and other methods including overloaded < operator
  void insertNextTrans(shared_ptr<Trans> t){ nextTrans.insert(t); }
  void removeNextTrans() { nextTrans.clear(); }

};

typedef set<shared_ptr<Place>, compare > PlacePointerSet;

class Trans{

//other data members
PlacePointerSet inPlaces;
PlacePointerSet outPlaces;

public:

//constructor and others including overloaded < operator
void insertInPlace(shared_ptr<Place> p){ 
     inPlaces.insert(p); 
     p->insertNextTrans(shared_ptr<Trans>(this)); }
void insertOutPlace(shared_ptr<Place> p){ //body }
void print() cosnt { //body }

};

class Net{
TransPointerSet acts;
//other data members
public:
//constructor and others
};
```

And here is my main for testing whether the classes are properly working or not.

```
int main()
{
 shared_ptr<Place> p1 = make_shared<Place>();
shared_ptr<Place> p2 = make_shared<Place>();
shared_ptr<Trans> t = make_shared<Trans>();
t->insertInPlace(p1);
t->insertOutPlace(p2);
t->print();
}
```

The problem is after successful compilation it ends up with 
"double free or corruption (fasttop) error" after t->print() properly working.
I realize the bug lies in the circular dependency created by firstly taking p1 as member of t->inPlaces which inserts t as member of p1. But I need this both way linking. Also, I tried to reset every member of nextTrans in class Place by a method after t->print(), but that didn't work because the pointers are in a set.
So can anyone suggest any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you can't make a shared pointer from `this` just like that. By doing it you now have *two* shared pointers to the `Trans` instance, both pointing to the same instance but with their separate reference counters. That means that both will try to `delete` the pointer.

You need to use [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). The linked reference page have a very good example of your problem.

Answer (score 5):

This line in `Trans::insertInPlace()`:

```
p->insertNextTrans(shared_ptr<Trans>(this));
```

creates a separate, unrelated shared pointer to the same object.  You need to use `std::enable_shared_from_this` for the `Trans` class:

```
class Trans: public std::enable_shared_from_this {
    // ....
};
```

Then in `Trans::insertInPlace()`:

```
p->insertNextTrans(shared_from_this());
```